# Opening email account

Tags: html

Each time I want to open yahoo mail I have this error message.

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>Z649Z1KYD1Z32RR1</RequestId>
<HostId>vMHvAUetV0Bo9V2I3I3617vyaFqHqUW1KubxN/9HVXknaLLg3RfDoCbgMSKCe9OToe4XKqSuR+s=</HostId>
</Error>
```

How can I get rid of it?
Please don't use complicated words, I am not a crack in programming.
Thank you
George

Comment: Nobody can help me? Please

Comment: What do you mean by "opening yahoo mail"? If it's a problem on Yahoo side, their support might be able to help you. Otherwise, please edit your question and describe, what you want to achieve and how.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem on Yahoo side. It works on my mobile phone, but not on my PC. Opening yahoo mail = read my mails. Instead of being able to access Yahoo mail I get this message as shown above

Comment: I see. But there must be some kind of difference between your PC and your mobile phone. Perhaps a browser plug-in or some (faulty) cached credentials. Have you tried another browser or incognito mode? If this doesn't help, Yahoo support might still be able to help you if you send them the error you posted.